# Do i need to cast integer param to string for varchar index to be used?

Tags: mysql, sql

When i query a varchar column (indexed) against an integer number, it runs extremely slow. I thought mysql was able to infer this and cast the parameter to string, but when i use an integer for filtering it avoids the index.

Is this ok? Is it a collation problem? Should i always cast manually integers to string for varchar index to work?

Running mysql 5.7

the varchar column is an external id, we do not control whether it's integer or alphanumeric. Sometimes the user wants to find an object by our internal integer id, sometimes by their id, so we use: WHERE id = ? or external_id = ?

Comment: But why do you _query a varchar column (indexed) against an integer number_? Poor table design?

Comment: the varchar column is an external id, we do not control whether it's integer or alphanumeric. Sometimes the user wants to find an object by our internal integer id, sometimes by their id, so we use:  WHERE id = ? or external_id = ?

Comment: @gammel I now see the comment which should have been part of the question. Unfortunately it changes your question totally.

Comment: it doesn't change it. the question was clear, should i manually cast or not an integer to string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It says here that](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html):

> In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point
> (double-precision) numbers. For example, a comparison of string and
> numeric operands takes place as a comparison of floating-point
> numbers.

Since you're comparing string column with an integer constant, MySQL will have to convert each value in the column to float for comparison and index might not be used (things might be different if it were the other way round i.e. integer column compared to string constant).

But more importantly, **such comparison will produce unexpected results**:

```
select '123abc' = 123 -- true
```

That being said, it is not very difficult to change this:

```
select '123abc' = 123 -- true
```

to this:

```
select '123abc' = '123' -- false
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 combinations of comparing a column (VARCHAR or INT) to a value (string or numeric).  *One* case is inefficient because no index is useful:

```
WHERE varchar_col = 123
```

It is because it cannot use an index and will convert each string to a number to do the test.

The other cases *can* use an index on the column.  (For other reasons, such an index may *or may not* actually be used.)

This is *not* slow:

```
WHERE int_col = "123"
```

because the `"123"` is converted to a simple number as it is parsed.

And, of course, these work "as expected".  That is a string comparison or a numeric comparison is used.

```
WHERE varchar_col = "123"
WHERE int_col     =  123
```

(`FLOAT` is another topic.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the data type or the collation, it's the fact that you're using `OR` to search two different columns.

Consider the analogy: suppose I ask you to find people named Gammel in the telephone book. You ask, "is that the last name or the first name?" I answer, "please find all cases, whether it's the first name or the last name."

Now you have a problem.

```
SELECT ... FROM telephone_book
WHERE last_name = 'Gammel' OR first_name = 'Gammel';
```

The book is sorted by last name, so it should be quick to find the entries that match the last name. But I also asked for all those that match the *first name.* Those may be distributed randomly all through the book, for people with any last name. You will now have to search the book the hard way, one page at a time.

A common solution to the `OR` optimization problem is to use `UNION` with two separate queries that search on respective indexes.

```
SELECT ... FROM telephone_book
WHERE last_name = 'Gammel' 
UNION
SELECT ... FROM telephone_book
WHERE first_name = 'Gammel';
```

Supposing there is a different index on `first_name`, the latter query in this union will use it to find the entries matching by first name in an optimized way. We already know it can do that for last name.

Then once the (hopefully small) subset of rows matching either condition are found, these sets are unioned together into one result.

Comment: Interesting. I'll verify this later.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

> Comparison of dissimilar columns (comparing a string column to a temporal or numeric column, for example) may prevent use of indexes if values cannot be compared directly without conversion. For a given value such as 1 in the numeric column, it might compare equal to any number of values in the string column such as '1', ' 1', '00001', or '01.e1'. This rules out use of any indexes for the string column.

For table like this:

```
create table test_user
(
    id   int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(45) default '' null
);

create index idx_name on test_user (name);
```

mysql **will use** index if column is compared with strings:

```
mysql> explain select * from test_user where name = 'fdsa';
+--+-----------+---------+----------+----+-------------+--------+-------+-----+----+--------+-----------+
|id|select_type|table    |partitions|type|possible_keys|key     |key_len|ref  |rows|filtered|Extra      |
+--+-----------+---------+----------+----+-------------+--------+-------+-----+----+--------+-----------+
|1 |SIMPLE     |test_user|null      |ref |idx_name     |idx_name|183    |const|1   |100     |Using index|
+--+-----------+---------+----------+----+-------------+--------+-------+-----+----+--------+-----------+
```

mysql **will not use** index if column is compared with integers:

```
mysql> explain select * from test_user where name = 1;

+--+-----------+---------+----------+-----+-------------+--------+-------+----+----+--------+------------------------+
|id|select_type|table    |partitions|type |possible_keys|key     |key_len|ref |rows|filtered|Extra                   |
+--+-----------+---------+----------+-----+-------------+--------+-------+----+----+--------+------------------------+
|1 |SIMPLE     |test_user|null      |index|idx_name     |idx_name|183    |null|1   |100     |Using where; Using index|
+--+-----------+---------+----------+-----+-------------+--------+-------+----+----+--------+------------------------+
```

On the other side, if column type is int, then mysql **will use** index.

```
explain select * from test_user where id = '1';
+--+-----------+---------+----------+-----+-------------+-------+-------+-----+----+--------+-----+
|id|select_type|table    |partitions|type |possible_keys|key    |key_len|ref  |rows|filtered|Extra|
+--+-----------+---------+----------+-----+-------------+-------+-------+-----+----+--------+-----+
|1 |SIMPLE     |test_user|null      |const|PRIMARY      |PRIMARY|4      |const|1   |100     |null |
+--+-----------+---------+----------+-----+-------------+-------+-------+-----+----+--------+-----+
```