# why mysql not using index when that index is based on a varchar field?

Tags: mysql

Say, I have a table that is:

```
create table test (
    id    int primary key auto_increment,
    c_no  varchar(11),
    c2    varchar(2),
    
    key c_no(c_no)
);
```

Then based on this table, I have a sql query which is:

```
select
    *
from
    test
where
    c_no = 100
```

But when I used explain to analyze the sql, I found it didn't use the index on c_no:

```
explain  select *  from test2 where c_no=100


+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test | NULL       | ALL  | c_no          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    7 |    14.29 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 3 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

why?

Comment: What are the "3 warnings" mentioned in MySQL's output?

Comment: How many rows does the table have? Most RDBMS will skip using indexes if they know the table is small (say, under 100 rows) as doing a direct table scan will be faster when you want to read columns outside the `INDEX INCLUDE` list (which you are doing as you're using `SELECT *`).

Comment: See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72233020/does-querying-int-column-with-string-datatype-have-any-performance-impact-in-mys/72233425#72233425 That question is about the opposite — querying an INT column with a string constant. But I explain the difference and give an example like yours, where you query a string column with an INT constant.

Answer (score 2):

When the column datatype is `VARCHAR()`, you need to wrap the searched value with quotes for the index to be in use.

So, instead of:

```
select *  from test where c_no=100;
```

.. try with:

```
select *  from test where c_no='100';
```

[Check the difference in this demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5EggPfos)

As for *"why?"* , I don't really have the exact answer to that because when I discovered this, I'm not concerned about why. However, I assume that you're searching a number (`INT`?) datatype on a `VARCHAR()` column which is a mismatch so that's why it doesn't recognize `=100` as varchar.

[Here's what happen if `c_no` column datatype is `INT`](https://dbfiddle.uk/BOw3ko34)